# Show hide elements with checkboxes and Jquery - jsfiddle example

Tags: jquery

This works fine if I don't check both boxes. Not sure how to fix it.

```
$(".home-check").live('click', function() {
if ($(".home-check").is(':checked')) {
    var ident = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.' + ident).hide();

} else {
    var identt = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.' + identt).show();
}
});​
<p><input class="home-check" id="water" type="checkbox" name="gethired" />Fire - Only Show Fire</p>
<p><input class="home-check" id="fire" type="checkbox" name="hire" />Water - Only Show Water</p>

<li class="fire">Fire</li>
<li class="water">Water</li>
<li class="fire">Fire</li>
<li class="water">Water</li>
<li class="fire">Fire</li>
<li class="water">Water</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cip691/AeyAL/2/

Comment: It is not clear which behaviour you expect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(".home-check").on('click', function() {
    var li_class = '.' +  this.id;    
    $(li_class).toggle();
});
```

​
Do not use live in this case it's not necessary, use toggle instead of show and hide = less code to write ;).

And instead of

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

use:

```
this.id
```

It will be quicker !

Hope it was useful !

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(".home-check").live('click', function() {
    $("li").hide();
    $(".home-check:checked").each(function() {
        $("." + this.id).show();
    });
});
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AeyAL/6/)

Note: your id's are the wrong way around for the labels, that's why checking `Fire` shows water and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(".home-check").is(':checked')) {
    var ident = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.' + ident).hide();

} else {
    var identt = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.' + identt).show();
}
```

don't you suppose that you are using the ID of the TAG? so change the "." for "#", and try it

```
if ($(".home-check").is(':checked')) {
    var ident = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + ident).hide();

} else {
    var identt = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + identt).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to get the [target object that initiated the event](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/). This way you can just act upon it directly instead of performing a search for a checked box which returns both items when you have them both checked.

```
$(".home-check").live('click', function (event) {
    var checkbox = event.target;
    var ident = $(checkbox).attr('id');

    if ($(checkbox).is(':checked')) {
        $('.' + ident).hide();

    } else {
        $('.' + ident).show();
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".home-check").live('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var ident = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.' + ident).hide();

   } else {
       var identt = $(this).attr('id');
       $('.' + identt).show();
   }
```

});​

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cip691/AeyAL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/HKQxH/

this will show and hide the li elements with the checkboxes.

The li must be hidden (i guess)

```
li{display:none;}​
```

the js

```
$(".home-check").live('click', function() {         
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        $('li.' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
        }
                      else{
                      $('li.' + $(this).attr('id')).hide();
                      }
});​
```

and the html (the "fire" and "water" are not in "order")

```
    <p><input class="home-check" id="water" type="checkbox" name="gethired" />Water</p>
<p><input class="home-check" id="fire" type="checkbox" name="hire" />Fire</p>

<li class="fire">Fire</li>
<li class="water">Water</li>
<li class="fire">Fire</li>
<li class="water">Water</li>
<li class="fire">Fire</li>
<li class="water">Water</li>

​
```